# How do you trinity grades align with RCM grades

Tags: piano, exam-grades, grading

I have been doing Trinity piano grades for the past 5 years. I am currently in grade 5. I want to learn a piece called "Waltz in C-Sharp Minor"(op. 64, no. 2) by Chopin. However, as it is not in the Trinity syllabus, I don't know what grade level or difficulty level it is in. So, as a result, it is a little difficult for me to decide if this is a piece of adequate difficulty for my grade level. I saw that RCM has graded it as a level 9 piece in their syllabus. I was wondering how the RCM grades compare with the Trinity grades, and how, by looking at other syllabuses, can I decide if a piece is a right fit for my grade level or not?